# ANN predictions are all the same

Tags: r, neural-network

I have trained and selected a certain topology for my ANN using RMSE to choose a topology with 18 hidden nodes.

```
best.ANN.f <- neuralnet(total_let_area ~ income + pop + prop_unemp + medianage + prop_bdegree + prop_vehicle, data = train, hidden = 18, threshold  =0.01, act.fct = "tanh", stepmax = 1e+07)
best.ANN.pred.f <- compute(best.ANN.f, test[,c("income", "pop", "prop_unemp", "medianage", "prop_bdegree", prop_vehicle")])
head(best.ANN.pred.f$net.result)
```

|------|---Prediction---|

|1-----| 37382.83899|

|2-----| 37382.83899|

|3-----| 37382.83899|

|4-----| 37382.83899|

|5-----| 37382.83899|

|6-----| 37382.83899|

When I run my holdout set of data through the ANN it predicts the same value for every row of my dataframe.

Does this mean I have overfit the data or is there somewhere else I am falling short.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that scaling my data has fixed the problem, if anyone else is having the same issue I would recommend to do this.